# Find all the real numbers an expression might take when $a, b, c$ are complex numbers of the same modulus.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Let $a, b, c$ be three complex numbers of the same modulus. Find all real numbers that might be equal to:
> $$x = \frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}$$

It is obvious that when all three numbers are equal, we might write that:
$$x = \frac{3a^3}{a^3} = 3 \in \mathbb{R}$$

I would write, in order to obtain real values:
$$x = \overline{x}$$

So:
$$\overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c} (a^3 + b^3 + c^3) = abc (\overline{a}^3 + \overline{b}^3 + \overline{c}^3)$$

But the calculations are quite harsh, the only thing I might use to solve them is that:
$$a\overline{a} = b\overline{b} = c\overline{c} = m^2$$
where $m$ is the complex modulus of the three numbers.

Comment: In the Complex plane, which Real nimbers have a modulus of $3$?

Comment: Hi... u guys deleted my answer. May i know the issue ? There are 3 conditions coming out of 3 conditions in my derivation: $\theta_a=\frac{(\theta_b+\theta_c)}{2}$ or $\theta_b=\frac{(\theta_a+\theta_c)}{2}$ or $\theta_c=\frac{(\theta_a+\theta_b)}{2}$. Are u saying there is a different set of conditions ? Check it..i think these are all the conditions both necessary and sufficient. Here $\theta_a$ is angle of $a$, $\theta_b$ is angle of $b$,$\theta_c$ is angle of $c$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us implement Mark Bennet's idea.

Let $\frac{a^3}{abc}=e^{i\alpha}$ and $\frac{b^3}{abc}=e^{i\beta}$, where $\alpha,\beta\in[0,2\pi)$. Then $\frac{c^3}{abc}=\frac{abc}{a^3}\frac{abc}{b^3}=\frac1{e^{i\alpha}}\frac1{e^{i\beta}}=e^{i(-(\alpha+\beta))}.$
$$\begin{aligned}x &= e^{i\alpha} + e^{i\beta}+e^{i(-(\alpha+\beta))}\\
&=(\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos(-(\alpha+\beta))) + i(\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin(-(\alpha+\beta)))\end{aligned}$$
Since $$\begin{aligned}&\quad\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin(-(\alpha+\beta))\\
&= 2\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}2-2\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\\
&=4\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\sin\frac\alpha2\sin\frac\beta2,
\end{aligned}$$
$x$ is real $\iff$ $\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}2=0$ or $\sin\frac\alpha2=0$ or $\sin\frac\beta2=0$ $\iff$ $\alpha+\beta=0$ or $\alpha=0$ or $\beta=0$.

- $\alpha=0$.
  $x=1+2\cos\beta\in[-1,3]$.
  Note $1+2\cos\beta$ is attainable as we can set $a=1$, $b=e^{i\frac\beta3}$, $c=1/b$.
- $\beta=0$.
  $x=1+2\cos\alpha\in[-1,3]$.
- $\alpha+\beta=0$.
  $x=1+2\cos\alpha\in[-1,3]$.

Hence, all possible real $x$s are $[-1,3]$.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easier than that - you can write your expression as the sum of three things each of which has modulus $1$. That limits the possible answers. The question is then, given those three things also have product $1$, which of the relevant points on the real line can you reach?

I think that should give you enough to get you started and you should be able to do some thinking of your own from there.